Unit testing business logic in React Context Providers, how to maintain legibility?
I am unsure of how best to unit test a React Context Provider with nontrivial business logic.
Here is one I've written that provides a working state for a list of items, maintains a  separate saved version of that state, and allows you to save an individual item, updating the state.
export const ItemsProvider = ({children, postToApi, initialItems}) => {
  
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
  const [error, setError] = useState('')
  const [localItems, localDispatch] = useReducer(itemsReducer, data)
  const [savedItems, savedItemsDispatch] = useReducer(itemsReducer, data)

  // Wrapper for API Requests
  const initRequest = (asyncRequest) => async (param) => {
    setLoading(true)
    try{
      await asyncRequest(param)
      setLoading(false)
    } catch(e) {
      setError(e as string)
      setLoading(false)
    }
  }

  // Save item, if new add to saved items, otherwise update with saved data. Update local state.
  const saveItem = initRequest(async (item) => {
    const savedItem = await postToApi(item)
    if(getIndexOfItemWithId(savedItem._id, savedItems) < 0){
      savedItemsDispatch({type: 'ADD_ITEM', payload: savedItem})
    } else {
      savedItemsDispatch({type: 'UPDATE_ITEM', id: item._id, payload: savedItem})
    }
    localDispatch({type: 'UPDATE_ITEM', id: item._id, payload: savedItem})
  })

  const itemState = {
    loading,
    error,
    savedItems,
    localItems,
    fields
  }

  const updaters = {
    saveItem
  }

  return (
    <ItemsContext.Provider value={itemState}> 
      <ItemsUpdateContext.Provider value={updaters}>
        {children}
      </ItemsUpdateContext.Provider>
    </ItemsContext.Provider>
  )
}

Functionally this works well enough, and is legible to me.
However, I want to be able to unit test the the business logic within the provider. I know traditional wisdom states we want to keep as few side effects in functions as possible so here is my stab at making saveItem a testable function:
export const saveItem = async(
  itemToSave
  savedItems
  savedItemsDispatch, 
  localItemsDispatch, 
  postMethod
) => {
  const savedItem = await postMethod(itemToSave)
  if(getIndexOfItemWithId(savedItem._id, savedItems) < 0){
    savedItemsDispatch({type: 'ADD_ITEM', payload: savedItem})
  } else {
    savedItemsDispatch({type: 'UPDATE_ITEM', id: itemToSave._id, payload: savedItem})
  }
  localItemsDispatch({type: 'UPDATE_ITEM', id: itemToSave._id, payload: savedItem})
}

Here I've moved any references to instance variables of the Provider to arguments. Now I can mock the the referenced functions and just focus on testing the business logic without having to create the Provider and deal with side effects that may result.
In my opinion, while this is more testable, it is less legible because of the many arguments and we lose some intuitive context by moving this function outside of the ItemsProvider scope. I feel if all of my business logic is written in the global scope maintainability becomes an issue.
This must be an issue that comes up often, but I am having trouble finding consistent opinions and resources referencing it. Does anyone here have good guidelines for how to make business logic both testable and legible?
